# Integration of Kubernetes for Dagster and dbt

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, dbt, dagster

Hi i am working on a project based on Dagster on K8s cluster. Part of the jobs in the DAG is to materialize dbt assets using spark engine. Previously i had everything in one single pod (spark, dbt and dagster) but now i have been requested to move the transformation engine on another pod and I pretty stuck as the load_assets_from_dbt_project uses local path. Moreover i do not have a full knowledge of K8s but i suppose that even if i attach a service to the dbt pod then dagster cannot see the path variable of the dbt project in the other pod.

As a solution i thought to use K8s job to build and launch dbt run inside a docker image but i would lose the dbt-dagster integration features like showing all the models written. Do you have any clue on how to divide the pods?

Answer (score 0):

In order to divide the pods into two: one for Spark and one for dbt and Dagster. The dbt and Dagster pod will need to be able to access the dbt project files, which are located in the Spark pod.

One solution is to use a Kubernetes persistent volume claim (PVC) to share the dbt project files between the two pods. Once a PVC is created, you can mount it to one or more pods to share the dbt project files between the two pods.

First create a PVC that points to the storage where the dbt project files are located.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dbt-project-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then mount the PVC to the dbt and Dagster pod and Set the  `dbt_project_dir`  variable in the dbt and Dagster pod to the mount path of the PVC as below-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dbt-dagster-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: dbt-dagster
      image: dagster/dbt:latest
      volumeMounts:
        - name: dbt-project-volume
          mountPath: /dbt_project
      env:
        - name: DBT_PROJECT_DIR
          value: /dbt_project

  volumes:
    - name: dbt-project-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: dbt-project-pvc
```

[image]

[Running Dagster with Kubernetes.](https://dagster.io/integrations/dagster-kubernetes)